# These reference conflicts are listed in the build log when log verbosity is set to detailed

Tags: c#, warnings, conflict, versions

I get the warning as stated in the title: Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly that could not be resolved.  These reference conflicts are listed in the build log when log verbosity is set to detailed.

But even though i change the log verbosity to detailed i don't get any information that can help me further with this issue.

I understand that there are different versions in my assembly, but how can i find out which?